# Is glue needed for an LPG pigtail hose

Tags: plumbing, leak, pipe

[image]We have a twin 45kg LPG gas cylinder setup.

One of the pigtail hoses had a gas leak and as such needs replacement.

I found a manual for our setup:[manual pdf](https://gasnz.org.nz/s/LPGA-COP-No2-November-2019_v4_final.pdf)

We've been able to find the correct pigtail hose according to this manual.(in Section: 4.5 a ii)

The problem is that the old pigtail hose appears to have some sort of glue around it and the manual doesn't specify anything about a sealant or glue.

What sort of glue/sealant should be used to connect the pigtail hose or is no glue needed?

Edit: Attached an image showing the setup.

The pipe on the right attached to the cylinder (the cylinder is mostly off screen) is the pigtail hose that needs to be replaced.

Comment: We really need a picture to know what you are talking about. What is a pigtail to you? Are the lines copper, or plastic,  or flex, or rigid pipe? LPG gas lines do not use glue- most of the connections need pipe sealant (sometimes called pipe dope) and/or teflon tape. Not all do, for example, flare fittings or ground joint fittings.

Comment: Must be pipe dope, not glue.

Comment: Might consider replacing both, unless you know of an abusive event the right suffered and the left didn't - presumably they are the same age, and if the right started leaking, the left may not be far behind, if due to old age/degradation.

Comment: I think there may be an adapter "fixed" in the regulator but the pigtail should come off leaving the adapter behind in the regulator. I think the connectors into the regulator are different sizes for a single vs dual/twin regulators. I think the pigtails for twin regulators are smaller (possibly 5/16" or 7/15" NPT) compared with pigtails for single regulators (possibly 1/4" NPT). I'm currently trying to figure this out for myself here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/263568/160827

Answer (score 1):

Tapered /pipe threads need pipe dope to seal. Generally teflon tape is most convenient. Flare connections are metal to metal seals and must be clean to seal; never use pipe dope. I am not certain what the various connection types are from the photo.