# Replace copper gas pigtails with stainless steel braided hoses

Tags: gas, plumbing-fixture

I'm in Australia. I have what I think is a bromic gas regulator with automatic changeover valve. I've only ever known it to be connected to a single gas bottle but would like to connect it to two bottles. I wanted to swap the copper pigtails over to stainless steel braided hoses with handwheels.
[image: Bromic regulator and auto changeover]

I bought the new s/s braided hoses (Bromic 6SCH0450) but the end which connects to the auto changeover valve has a larger connector (1/2" NPT i think) than the original copper pigtails (3/8" NPT i think).
[image: pigtail connectors]

The auto changeover valve has what looks to be a copper adapter in its outlets. This seems to make sense, since online this bromic is stated as having a 1/2" NPT outlet. However, I can't seem to remove them.
[image: bromic auto changeover outlet]

Does anyone have experience with this sort of thing? Can/should I keep trying to remove the copper "adapter" still in the changeover valve? I risk rounding the nut and assume its a standard thread direction (anticlockwise to loosen?) Should I get another adapter to convert my 1/2" male NPT hose to 3/8" NPT and connect to the auto changeover (with the "adapter" still in there)? Get different hose with a 3/8" NPT end to it?

Comment: Those aren't stainless.  They're rubber, with a pretty stainless braid. The copper is actual copper.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks...clarified the s/s pipes are in fact braided hoses... just in case that makes a significant difference.

Comment: I would think using a rubber/plastic hose for a permanent gas installation would not be allowed, but have little knowledge of gas plumbing practices. What are you trying to achieve that the copper pipe isn't allowing?

Comment: @Armand These braided gas hoses meet the relevant Australian standards and can be used in place of copper pigtails which tend to stress and fracture with regular connection/disconnection from LPG bottles. I want to achieve a more flexible connection, less prone to breakage.